# REST JAX-RS javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:

Tags: java, rest, jboss, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am getting below exception whenever my REST client code makes a call to the REST service using below code:
**Code:**

```
public void putWatcher(Watcher watcher)
    {
        System.out.println("In REST Client putWatcher.***********");

        target = target.path(RESOURCE_WATCHERS).path(watcher.getWatcheruri());
        System.out.println(target.getUri());
        Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
        builder.put(Entity.json(watcher));
//      Response response = target.request().put(Entity.json(watcher));
        System.out.println("Returned from REST Call");
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.put(JerseyInvocation.java:318)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses$StatusImpl.<init>(Statuses.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses$StatusImpl.<init>(Statuses.java:54)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses.from(Statuses.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    ... 29 more
```

My **REST service is deployed on Tomcat 8** server and the **client code is deployed on JBoss 7.2.**
The client application is SIP-Servlets application which also bundles REST client.

When I test the client as a standalone Java Application it works but when deployed on JBoss it gives the error.
**My POM file is:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- logging dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- web j2ee dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- sip dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.servlet.sip</groupId>
    <artifactId>sip-servlets-spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.FINAL</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I also try to do as suggested on this link https://github.com/gondor/openstack4j/issues/30
It says to disable JAX-RS from JBOSS config standalone.xml. I am using standalone-sip.xml while starting the server so I modified that only. Removed these two lines:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
```

This also is not working. I don't know how to disable, just searched for JAX-RS and deleted those lines where I found those.

In one SO post there was a suggestion to use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response respone` instead of `Response response` tried that also but no luck.

One more info: the REST call itself is successful, that I can see on tomcat server.

Please suggest what else can be done.

Thanks

Comment: I got this exception when generating token we havent passed client id and secret,grant type all these parameters programatically.

Answer (score 9):

I recently bumped into this problem. It was caused by a library providing an old implementation of `javax.ws.rs.core`. I fixed it as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family; -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of jsr should I use instead, in case I have to mantain it?

Comment: Yes this work, but i don't understand how... Shouldn't we have to replace this 'old implementation' instead of just remove it? How did you come up with this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Can you take a look at libraries catalogue of your JBoss instance and remove all implementations of JAX-WS? To me it seems they conflict with the Jersey you bundle in your WAR-file.

Edit:

Actually I guess you need to resolve JAX-WS version conflict between your server and web application. Method *familyOf* you are missing in *Response.Status.Family* was introduced in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.Family.html) but is missing from [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.Family.html). So find Java EE 6 compatible Jersey version or upgrade the server.

And if later Maven will cause problems, then for the real kick, there's also

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and

```
<dependency>
...
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>...</exclusion>
```

Comment: If I delete the jar then JBoss doesn't start.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered a similar error. "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;"

Root cause: web service performance tester invoke the web service using script without passing in correct request body. 
missing a "/" in the path url of web service call is another case.

when you see this validation error, that means some major error already happened, this noSuchMethodError is only a minor byproduct when handling the major error.