# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException when using jrs-rest-java-client API

Tags: rest, jasperserver, jersey-client

I was trying to connect to Jasper Report Server using rest API and following is my Java code

```
RestClientConfiguration configuration = new RestClientConfiguration("http://localhost:8181/jasperserver");

JasperserverRestClient client = new JasperserverRestClient(configuration);

Session session = client.authenticate("jasperadmin", "jasperadmin");
session.logout();
OperationResult<InputStream> result = client
        .authenticate("jasperadmin", "jasperadmin")
        .reportingService()
        .report("/reports/samples/EmpTry")
        .prepareForRun(ReportOutputFormat.HTML, 1)
        .run();
InputStream report = result.getEntity();
```

but I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:412)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:321)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.SessionStorage.login(SessionStorage.java:102)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.SessionStorage.init(SessionStorage.java:93)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.SessionStorage.<init>(SessionStorage.java:50)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.JasperserverRestClient.authenticate(JasperserverRestClient.java:35)
at Zz.main(Zz.java:17)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses$StatusImpl.<init>(Statuses.java:63)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses$StatusImpl.<init>(Statuses.java:54)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses.from(Statuses.java:93)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:278)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:182)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:227)
... 14 more
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312491/rest-jax-rs-javax-ws-rs-processingexception which looks very similar

Comment: Finally got the solution. Had to edit the weblogic.xml file

Comment: Could you please post your answer so others might benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using weblogic server for my applicaion. So some jar files need to be specified in the weblogic.xml file. Below given is how my weblogic.xml will looks like.

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>   
   <wls:prefer-application-packages>
      <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
  </wls:prefer-application-packages>
 </wls:container-descriptor>
```

And also make sure that you are using the same versions of jersey. There are two different version available and if you use both together it show error.